# Excel Formula - Mapping Entire Column to Each Row of Another Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of products and a list of stores in two different documents. I want to create a third document where every product is in the same row as each unique id of stores. For example: Stores 1, 2, 3, 4 && Products V, W, X, Y, Z. Store 1 should have 5 rows of data so it's 1V, 1W, 1X, 1Y, 1Z (and so on for other stores). How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking where to start with this and haven't shown any work so I assume that you need the most basic of starting points?

Your pseudocode is something like this:

```
Create 2 dimensional array where 1st dimension is as large as store list and second dimension is as long as product list
Loop through array first dimension
  loop through array second dimension
    combine store string and product string with each iteration of loop
finish looping
paste array values into new sheet
```

You can look up "Excel VBA how to X" where X is each of those lines... more or less. If you get stuck at a point, open a new question, paste your code into the question and explain what you tried, what isn't working, etc and we can assist with that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So far I've literally manually created new rows and did it all one by one and realized this needs to scale to hundreds of items in hundreds of stores but wasn't sure where to start. I'll definitely do what you suggested. Thanks!