# EXCEL-VBA: Concatenate n rows with each line of another column

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I am stuck with what I though was a simple action to ask excel.
I need to concatenate each and every line of a column with each of the column of a second column.
This is what I would like to do

| Column A | Column B | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | XX | AA XX |
| BB | YY | AA YY |
| CC | ZZ | AA ZZ |
|  | ..n | BB XX |
|  |  | BB YY |
|  |  | BB ZZ |
|  |  | CC XX |
|  |  | CC YY |
|  |  | CC ZZ |
|  |  | AA ..n |
|  |  | BB ..n |
|  |  | CC ..n |

I tried to look into the existing questions, but maybe I don't know which keywords to use, I can't find a good code.The closest I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025858/excel-formula-mapping-entire-column-to-each-row-of-another-column) but I can't "translate" the pseudocode mentioned: I'm lost with the "iterration" mentionned

Could you please help me?

Txs very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If column C have only a title, below code does the work:

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1").Select  ' Select 1st row of column A
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select  ' Move to last row in column A
    last_col_A = ActiveCell.Row  ' Get last row number in column A
    
    Range("B1").Select  ' Select 1st row of column B
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select  ' Move to last row in column B
    last_col_B = ActiveCell.Row  ' Get last row number in column A
    
    row_C = 2 ' Start from second row of column C
    For rowA = 2 To last_col_A
        For rowB = 2 To last_col_B
            Range("C" & row_C).Value = Range("A" & rowA).Value & " " & Range("B" & rowB).Value
            row_C = row_C + 1  ' Increment row number
        Next
    Next        
End Sub
```

Comment: ... just some hints: a) use `Option Explicit` enforcing variable type declaration; b) fully qualify your range references (e.g. via sheet Code(Name) `Sheet1.Range("A1")` or tabular sheetname string like e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName").Range("A1")`) as the current active sheet referenced by default need not be the one in focus; consider use of a `With` - `End With` structure; d) [avoid using `Select` in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba); e) loops in cells are time consuming compared with loops in a datafield array

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***
*If your column names are not auto-generated, you may need to edit `Column1` and `Column2` to whatever the actual column names are (eg: `Column1=>ColumnA`)*

```
let

//change Table name in next line to actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),

//for each entry in Column 1, create a List of all the entries in Column 2
//then remove column 2 and expand the custom column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "List of all in Column2", 
            each #"Changed Type"[Column2]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column2"}),
    #"Expanded List of all in Column2" = Table.ExpandListColumn(
        #"Removed Columns", "List of all in Column2"),

//remove the rows with nulls
//  (happens if one column longer than the other
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded List of all in Column2", 
        each ([Column1] <> null) and ([List of all in Column2] <> null)),

//merge the two columns with space delimiter to get Results
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Filtered Rows",
        {"Column1", "List of all in Column2"},
        Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Result")
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Instructive & helpful +:)